# Accessing the database created on SQL Server 2008 R2 on a SQL Server 2005 installation on a different server

Tags: sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a database created on SQL Server 2008 R2 hosted on Server A. For some weird reasons, I might have to access this database from SQL Server 2005 installation on a different server.

The question is, would this be possible, can I access a 2008 R2 created database on SQL Server 2005? If yes, would there be any problems or issues that I should be expecting while doing so?

I'm a newbie to this whole SQL Server and .Net world, I might not have provided all the information that's needed here for you guys to provide an answer, so I apologize before hand. Please help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Cumulative update package 5](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/943656) for SQL Server 2005 Service Pack 2 to connect to 2008.

Comment: I'm sorry, I guess you understood my question wrong. I would like to connect to a database on 2008 from 2005

Comment: What do you mean by "access"? I understood that you want to use SQL Server Management Studio 2005 to connect to a 2008 instance. You can do that using the cumulative update I mentioned. See here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/946127